# GUI with GTK with several memory leaks

Tags: valgrind, gtk3

For short time I started to learn  `GTK-3.0` and I started to create a GUI for a program I work.

The program compiles fine with no warnings but when I run it with `valgrind` I see a lot of memory leaks and I can't figure out what I'm doing Wrong here.

I reduced my program to a minimal code which make it easy for you to explain the problem.

To following code compiles fine but with lots of memory leaks:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);
    GtkWidget *window;
    window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);

    g_signal_connect(window, "delete-event", G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);
    gtk_widget_show(window);
    gtk_main();
}
```

I compile it with:

```
gcc -Wpedantic -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror  -Wstrict-prototypes  -Wmissing-prototypes -Wold-style-definition -Wconversion -Wshadow -Winit-self -Wfloat-equal -Wwrite-strings -O0 -g main.c -o app `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0 ` `pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0 `
```

and after I run `valgrind` with the following command:

```
valgrind --leak-check=full --track-origins=yes --leak-check=full ./app
```

I get the following Output:

```
==14405== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==14405== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==14405== Using Valgrind-3.11.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==14405== Command: ./app
==14405== 
==14405== 
==14405== HEAP SUMMARY:
==14405==     in use at exit: 1,243,902 bytes in 12,774 blocks
==14405==   total heap usage: 80,535 allocs, 67,761 frees, 6,190,649 bytes allocated
==14405== 
==14405== 16 bytes in 1 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 1,279 of 5,945
==14405==    at 0x4C2FB55: calloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==14405==    by 0x86E2780: g_malloc0 (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.4800.1)
==14405==    by 0x5796522: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.4800.1)
==14405==    by 0x579AF90: g_type_register_fundamental (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.4800.1)
==14405==    by 0x577A30B: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.4800.1)
==14405==    by 0x5774177: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.4800.1)
==14405==    by 0x40104E9: call_init.part.0 (dl-init.c:72)
==14405==    by 0x40105FA: call_init (dl-init.c:30)
==14405==    by 0x40105FA: _dl_init (dl-init.c:120)
==14405==    by 0x4000CF9: ??? (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so)
==14405== 
==14405== 16 bytes in 1 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 1,280 of 5,945
==14405==    at 0x4C2DB8F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==14405==    by 0x4C2FDEF: realloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==14405==    by 0x86E27E7: g_realloc (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.4800.1)
==14405==    by 0x5796406: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.4800.1)
==14405==    by 0x579AF90: g_type_register_fundamental (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.4800.1)
==14405==    by 0x577A30B: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.4800.1)
==14405==    by 0x5774177: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.4800.1)
==14405==    by 0x40104E9: call_init.part.0 (dl-init.c:72)
==14405==    by 0x40105FA: call_init (dl-init.c:30)
==14405==    by 0x40105FA: _dl_init (dl-init.c:120)
==14405==    by 0x4000CF9: ??? (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so)
==14405== 
==14405== 16 bytes in 1 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 1,281 of 5,945
==14405==    at 0x4C2FB55: calloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==14405==    by 0x86E2780: g_malloc0 (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.4800.1)
==14405==    by 0x5796522: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.4800.1)
==14405==    by 0x579AF90: g_type_register_fundamental (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.4800.1)
==14405==    by 0x577A371: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.4800.1)
==14405==    by 0x5774177: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.4800.1)
==14405==    by 0x40104E9: call_init.part.0 (dl-init.c:72)
==14405==    by 0x40105FA: call_init (dl-init.c:30)
==14405==    by 0x40105FA: _dl_init (dl-init.c:120)
==14405==    by 0x4000CF9: ??? (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so)
==14405== 
==14405== 16 bytes in 1 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 1,282 of 5,945
==14405==    at 0x4C2DB8F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==14405==    by 0x4C2FDEF: realloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==14405==    by 0x86E27E7: g_realloc (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.4800.1)
==14405==    by 0x5796406: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.4800.1)
==14405==    by 0x579AF90: g_type_register_fundamental (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.4800.1)
==14405==    by 0x577A371: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.4800.1)
==14405==    by 0x5774177: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.4800.1)
==14405==    by 0x40104E9: call_init.part.0 (dl-init.c:72)
==14405==    by 0x40105FA: call_init (dl-init.c:30)
==14405==    by 0x40105FA: _dl_init (dl-init.c:120)
==14405==    by 0x4000CF9: ??? (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so)
==14405== 
==14405== 16 bytes in 1 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 1,283 of 5,945
==14405==    at 0x4C2FB55: calloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==14405==    by 0x86E2780: g_malloc0 (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.4800.1)
==14405==    by 0x5796522: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.4800.1)
==14405==    by 0x579AF90: g_type_register_fundamental (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.4800.1)
==14405==    by 0x5783B04: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.4800.1)
==14405==    by 0x5774181: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.4800.1)
==14405==    by 0x40104E9: call_init.part.0 (dl-init.c:72)
==14405==    by 0x40105FA: call_init (dl-init.c:30)
==14405==    by 0x40105FA: _dl_init (dl-init.c:120)
==14405==    by 0x4000CF9: ??? (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so)
==14405== 
==14405== 16 bytes in 1 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 1,284 of 5,945
==14405==    at 0x4C2DB8F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==14405==    by 0x4C2FDEF: realloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==14405==    by 0x86E27E7: g_realloc (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.4800.1)
==14405==    by 0x5796406: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.4800.1)
==14405==    by 0x579AF90: g_type_register_fundamental (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.4800.1)
==14405==    by 0x5783B04: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.4800.1)
==14405==    by 0x5774181: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.4800.1)
==14405==    by 0x40104E9: call_init.part.0 (dl-init.c:72)
==14405==    by 0x40105FA: call_init (dl-init.c:30)
==14405==    by 0x40105FA: _dl_init (dl-init.c:120)
==14405==    by 0x4000CF9: ??? (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so)
==14405== 
==14405== 16 bytes in 1 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 1,285 of 5,945
==14405==    at 0x4C2FB55: calloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==14405==    by 0x86E2780: g_malloc0 (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.4800.1)
==14405==    by 0x5796522: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.4800.1)
==14405==    by 0x579AF90: g_type_register_fundamental (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.4800.1)
==14405==    by 0x577EC1B: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.4800.1)
==14405==    by 0x5774186: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.4800.1)
==14405==    by 0x40104E9: call_init.part.0 (dl-init.c:72)
==14405==    by 0x40105FA: call_init (dl-init.c:30)
==14405==    by 0x40105FA: _dl_init (dl-init.c:120)
==14405==    by 0x4000CF9: ??? (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so)
==14405== 
==14405== 16 bytes in 1 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 1,286 of 5,945
==14405==    at 0x4C2DB8F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==14405==    by 0x4C2FDEF: realloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==14405==    by 0x86E27E7: g_realloc (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.4800.1)
==14405==    by 0x5796406: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.4800.1)
==14405==    by 0x579AF90: g_type_register_fundamental (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.4800.1)
==14405==    by 0x577EC1B: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.4800.1)
==14405==    by 0x5774186: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.4800.1)
==14405==    by 0x40104E9: call_init.part.0 (dl-init.c:72)
==14405==    by 0x40105FA: call_init (dl-init.c:30)
==14405==    by 0x40105FA: _dl_init (dl-init.c:120)
==14405==    by 0x4000CF9: ??? (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so)
==14405== 
==14405== 24 bytes in 1 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 1,808 of 5,945
==14405==    at 0x4C2FB55: calloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==14405==    by 0x86E2780: g_malloc0 (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.4800.1)
==14405==    by 0x57993B5: g_type_class_ref (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.4800.1)
==14405==    by 0x5798E2C: g_type_class_ref (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.4800.1)
==14405==    by 0x5788147: g_param_spec_flags (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.4800.1)
==14405==    by 0x5191F6F: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0.1800.9)
==14405==    by 0x579922C: g_type_class_ref (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.4800.1)
==14405==    by 0x4EBFC49: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0.1800.9)
==14405==    by 0x7532A1D: atk_add_focus_tracker (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libatk-1.0.so.0.21809.1)
==14405==    by 0x4EC0084: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0.1800.9)
==14405==    by 0x5778FA4: g_closure_invoke (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.4800.1)
==14405==    by 0x578AFC0: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.4800.1)
==14405== 
==14405== 32 bytes in 1 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 2,824 of 5,945
==14405==    at 0x4C2FB55: calloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==14405==    by 0x86E2780: g_malloc0 (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.4800.1)
==14405==    by 0x57993B5: g_type_class_ref (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.4800.1)
==14405==    by 0x5798E2C: g_type_class_ref (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.4800.1)
==14405==    by 0x5788057: g_param_spec_enum (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.4800.1)
==14405==    by 0x5FCBAFE: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdk-3.so.0.1800.9)
==14405==    by 0x579922C: g_type_class_ref (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.4800.1)
==14405==    by 0x5798E2C: g_type_class_ref (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.4800.1)
==14405==    by 0x57803A3: g_object_new_valist (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.4800.1)
==14405==    by 0x5780520: g_object_new (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.4800.1)
==14405==    by 0x5FF16DD: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdk-3.so.0.1800.9)
==14405==    by 0x5FF3E21: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdk-3.so.0.1800.9)
==14405== 
==14405== 56 bytes in 1 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 3,553 of 5,945
==14405==    at 0x4C2FD5F: realloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==14405==    by 0x86E27E7: g_realloc (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.4800.1)
==14405==    by 0x57959D8: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.4800.1)
==14405==    by 0x579B2CC: g_type_register_static (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.4800.1)
==14405==    by 0x577A53D: g_flags_register_static (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.4800.1)
==14405==    by 0x50A2D0A: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0.1800.9)
==14405==    by 0x4FB9264: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0.1800.9)
==14405==    by 0x579922C: g_type_class_ref (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.4800.1)
==14405==    by 0x57803A3: g_object_new_valist (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.4800.1)
==14405==    by 0x5780520: g_object_new (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.4800.1)
==14405==    by 0x4FBAAB7: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0.1800.9)
==14405==    by 0x4FBAE82: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0.1800.9)
==14405== 
==14405== 80 bytes in 1 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 4,221 of 5,945
==14405==    at 0x4C2FB55: calloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==14405==    by 0x86E2780: g_malloc0 (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.4800.1)
==14405==    by 0x57993B5: g_type_class_ref (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.4800.1)
==14405==    by 0x5798E2C: g_type_class_ref (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.4800.1)
==14405==    by 0x579C247: g_type_create_instance (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.4800.1)
==14405==    by 0x57840D2: g_param_spec_internal (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.4800.1)
==14405==    by 0x5788661: g_param_spec_object (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.4800.1)
==14405==    by 0x5FD1231: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdk-3.so.0.1800.9)
==14405==    by 0x579922C: g_type_class_ref (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.4800.1)
==14405==    by 0x577FDAC: g_object_newv (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.4800.1)
==14405==    by 0x5780533: g_object_new (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.4800.1)
==14405==    by 0x5FD1324: gdk_display_manager_get (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdk-3.so.0.1800.9)
==14405== 
==14405== 96 bytes in 1 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 5,132 of 5,945
==14405==    at 0x4C2FB55: calloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==14405==    by 0x86E2780: g_malloc0 (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.4800.1)
==14405==    by 0x5795A59: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.4800.1)
==14405==    by 0x5795B43: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.4800.1)
==14405==    by 0x57740AA: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.4800.1)
==14405==    by 0x40104E9: call_init.part.0 (dl-init.c:72)
==14405==    by 0x40105FA: call_init (dl-init.c:30)
==14405==    by 0x40105FA: _dl_init (dl-init.c:120)
==14405==    by 0x4000CF9: ??? (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so)
==14405== 
==14405== 96 bytes in 1 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 5,133 of 5,945
==14405==    at 0x4C2FB55: calloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==14405==    by 0x86E2780: g_malloc0 (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.4800.1)
==14405==    by 0x5795A59: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.4800.1)
==14405==    by 0x5795B43: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.4800.1)
==14405==    by 0x579AF82: g_type_register_fundamental (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.4800.1)
==14405==    by 0x577A30B: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.4800.1)
==14405==    by 0x5774177: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.4800.1)
==14405==    by 0x40104E9: call_init.part.0 (dl-init.c:72)
==14405==    by 0x40105FA: call_init (dl-init.c:30)
==14405==    by 0x40105FA: _dl_init (dl-init.c:120)
==14405==    by 0x4000CF9: ??? (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so)
==14405== 
==14405== 96 bytes in 1 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 5,134 of 5,945
==14405==    at 0x4C2FB55: calloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==14405==    by 0x86E2780: g_malloc0 (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.4800.1)
==14405==    by 0x5795A59: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.4800.1)
==14405==    by 0x5795B43: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.4800.1)
==14405==    by 0x579AF82: g_type_register_fundamental (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.4800.1)
==14405==    by 0x577A371: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.4800.1)
==14405==    by 0x5774177: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.4800.1)
==14405==    by 0x40104E9: call_init.part.0 (dl-init.c:72)
==14405==    by 0x40105FA: call_init (dl-init.c:30)
==14405==    by 0x40105FA: _dl_init (dl-init.c:120)
==14405==    by 0x4000CF9: ??? (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so)
==14405== 
==14405== 96 bytes in 1 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 5,135 of 5,945
==14405==    at 0x4C2FB55: calloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==14405==    by 0x86E2780: g_malloc0 (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.4800.1)
==14405==    by 0x5795A59: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.4800.1)
==14405==    by 0x5795B43: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.4800.1)
==14405==    by 0x579AF82: g_type_register_fundamental (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.4800.1)
==14405==    by 0x5783B04: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.4800.1)
==14405==    by 0x5774181: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.4800.1)
==14405==    by 0x40104E9: call_init.part.0 (dl-init.c:72)
==14405==    by 0x40105FA: call_init (dl-init.c:30)
==14405==    by 0x40105FA: _dl_init (dl-init.c:120)
==14405==    by 0x4000CF9: ??? (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so)
==14405== 
==14405== 96 bytes in 1 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 5,136 of 5,945
==14405==    at 0x4C2FB55: calloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==14405==    by 0x86E2780: g_malloc0 (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.4800.1)
==14405==    by 0x5795A59: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.4800.1)
==14405==    by 0x5795B43: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.4800.1)
==14405==    by 0x579AF82: g_type_register_fundamental (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.4800.1)
==14405==    by 0x577EC1B: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.4800.1)
==14405==    by 0x5774186: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.4800.1)
==14405==    by 0x40104E9: call_init.part.0 (dl-init.c:72)
==14405==    by 0x40105FA: call_init (dl-init.c:30)
==14405==    by 0x40105FA: _dl_init (dl-init.c:120)
==14405==    by 0x4000CF9: ??? (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so)
==14405== 
==14405== 132 bytes in 1 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 5,413 of 5,945
==14405==    at 0x4C2FB55: calloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==14405==    by 0x86E2780: g_malloc0 (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.4800.1)
==14405==    by 0x5796DFF: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.4800.1)
==14405==    by 0x579AFE0: g_type_register_fundamental (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.4800.1)
==14405==    by 0x577A30B: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.4800.1)
==14405==    by 0x5774177: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.4800.1)
==14405==    by 0x40104E9: call_init.part.0 (dl-init.c:72)
==14405==    by 0x40105FA: call_init (dl-init.c:30)
==14405==    by 0x40105FA: _dl_init (dl-init.c:120)
==14405==    by 0x4000CF9: ??? (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so)
==14405== 
==14405== 132 bytes in 1 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 5,414 of 5,945
==14405==    at 0x4C2FB55: calloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==14405==    by 0x86E2780: g_malloc0 (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.4800.1)
==14405==    by 0x5796DFF: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.4800.1)
==14405==    by 0x579AFE0: g_type_register_fundamental (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.4800.1)
==14405==    by 0x577A371: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.4800.1)
==14405==    by 0x5774177: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.4800.1)
==14405==    by 0x40104E9: call_init.part.0 (dl-init.c:72)
==14405==    by 0x40105FA: call_init (dl-init.c:30)
==14405==    by 0x40105FA: _dl_init (dl-init.c:120)
==14405==    by 0x4000CF9: ??? (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so)
==14405== 
==14405== 148 bytes in 1 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 5,457 of 5,945
==14405==    at 0x4C2FB55: calloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==14405==    by 0x86E2780: g_malloc0 (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.4800.1)
==14405==    by 0x5796BD6: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.4800.1)
==14405==    by 0x579AFE0: g_type_register_fundamental (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.4800.1)
==14405==    by 0x5783B04: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.4800.1)
==14405==    by 0x5774181: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.4800.1)
==14405==    by 0x40104E9: call_init.part.0 (dl-init.c:72)
==14405==    by 0x40105FA: call_init (dl-init.c:30)
==14405==    by 0x40105FA: _dl_init (dl-init.c:120)
==14405==    by 0x4000CF9: ??? (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so)
==14405== 
==14405== 148 bytes in 1 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 5,458 of 5,945
==14405==    at 0x4C2FB55: calloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==14405==    by 0x86E2780: g_malloc0 (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.4800.1)
==14405==    by 0x5796BD6: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.4800.1)
==14405==    by 0x579AFE0: g_type_register_fundamental (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.4800.1)
==14405==    by 0x577EC1B: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.4800.1)
==14405==    by 0x5774186: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.4800.1)
==14405==    by 0x40104E9: call_init.part.0 (dl-init.c:72)
==14405==    by 0x40105FA: call_init (dl-init.c:30)
==14405==    by 0x40105FA: _dl_init (dl-init.c:120)
==14405==    by 0x4000CF9: ??? (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so)
==14405== 
==14405== 176 bytes in 4 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 5,513 of 5,945
==14405==    at 0x4C2DB8F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==14405==    by 0x86E2728: g_malloc (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.4800.1)
==14405==    by 0x4FA7173: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0.1800.9)
==14405==    by 0x4FA7439: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0.1800.9)
==14405==    by 0x4FA622C: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0.1800.9)
==14405==    by 0x4F02766: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0.1800.9)
==14405==    by 0x4F03FE4: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0.1800.9)
==14405==    by 0x4F0425D: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0.1800.9)
==14405==    by 0x577E896: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.4800.1)
==14405==    by 0x57801B4: g_object_new_valist (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.4800.1)
==14405==    by 0x5780520: g_object_new (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.4800.1)
==14405==    by 0x4F02D27: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0.1800.9)
==14405== 
==14405== 184 bytes in 1 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 5,528 of 5,945
==14405==    at 0x4C2FD5F: realloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==14405==    by 0x86E27E7: g_realloc (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.4800.1)
==14405==    by 0x57959D8: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.4800.1)
==14405==    by 0x579B2CC: g_type_register_static (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.4800.1)
==14405==    by 0x5785799: g_param_type_register_static (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.4800.1)
==14405==    by 0x5787AFB: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.4800.1)
==14405==    by 0x577418B: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.4800.1)
==14405==    by 0x40104E9: call_init.part.0 (dl-init.c:72)
==14405==    by 0x40105FA: call_init (dl-init.c:30)
==14405==    by 0x40105FA: _dl_init (dl-init.c:120)
==14405==    by 0x4000CF9: ??? (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so)
==14405== 
==14405== 200 bytes in 5 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 5,549 of 5,945
==14405==    at 0x4C2DB8F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==14405==    by 0x86E2728: g_malloc (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.4800.1)
==14405==    by 0x86FB537: g_memdup (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.4800.1)
==14405==    by 0x4FA7109: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0.1800.9)
==14405==    by 0x4FA7387: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0.1800.9)
==14405==    by 0x4FA61EC: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0.1800.9)
==14405==    by 0x50EFD11: gtk_style_context_set_state (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0.1800.9)
==14405==    by 0x4F03EE4: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0.1800.9)
==14405==    by 0x4F0425D: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0.1800.9)
==14405==    by 0x577E896: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.4800.1)
==14405==    by 0x57801B4: g_object_new_valist (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.4800.1)
==14405==    by 0x5780520: g_object_new (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.4800.1)
==14405== 
==14405== 336 bytes in 1 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 5,673 of 5,945
==14405==    at 0x4C2FB55: calloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==14405==    by 0x40136D4: allocate_dtv (dl-tls.c:322)
==14405==    by 0x40136D4: _dl_allocate_tls (dl-tls.c:539)
==14405==    by 0x59C42AE: allocate_stack (allocatestack.c:588)
==14405==    by 0x59C42AE: pthread_create@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (pthread_create.c:539)
==14405==    by 0x87218AF: ??? (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.4800.1)
==14405==    by 0x8703E9E: ??? (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.4800.1)
==14405==    by 0x8703F57: g_thread_new (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.4800.1)
==14405==    by 0x86DE280: ??? (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.4800.1)
==14405==    by 0x8392E16: g_task_get_type (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0.4800.1)
==14405==    by 0x83F0610: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0.4800.1)
==14405==    by 0x83E4216: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0.4800.1)
==14405== 
==14405== 
==14405== LEAK SUMMARY:
==14405==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==14405==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==14405==      possibly lost: 3,544 bytes in 35 blocks
==14405==    still reachable: 1,160,006 bytes in 12,091 blocks
==14405==                       of which reachable via heuristic:
==14405==                         length64           : 4,080 bytes in 72 blocks
==14405==                         newarray           : 2,112 bytes in 52 blocks
==14405==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==14405== Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not shown.
==14405== To see them, rerun with: --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all
==14405== 
==14405== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==14405== ERROR SUMMARY: 28 errors from 28 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

After I read a book and followed the [GTK3 Manual](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWindow.html#gtk-window-new) and I just can figure out where is the leak here.

Did I started wrong with the GUI here? From the manual I'm almost sure that I code it in the right way.

I see in the `valgrind` output that `calloc`  and `realloc` was called, this means that it should be a `free()` call needed too.
How do I release that memory with GTK+, if I must do it?

Answer (score 3):

This has been answered here many times. This is what I gave as an answer to someone else who asked this on a forum that I used to moderate:

> GTK+ is pretty lazy when it comes to allocating and deallocating internal buffers needed for the life time of the application. For example it may allocate an area of memory for a lookup table during initialisation which is needed for the life of the application. GTK+ will then never deallocate this. To Valgrind this looks like a memory leak, (which technically it is) but as an optimisation GTK+ does not deallocate it as it will be deallocated during application exit and so not an error. This is why you need suppression files so that Valgrind can ignore these. The problem is that you will need to change these with most GTK+ version changes.

What you are seeing are false positives. You can use a suppression file so that valgrind can ignore these. You can create your own or search for one already done.

Comment: What are you saying here I found also on internet, but without any example. Please provide an Example to your  Answer. The program I intend to create will run atleast 45 days if everything will be ok. So I need to fix this.

Comment: @Michi What Errol... is saying is, that valgrind shows "problems", that are actually are none (= "false positive"). It looks like there is a problem, but there is not. So you can ignore it.

Comment: @DarkTrick Since 2016 there are many changes, but one always remains: Debugging glib is the worst thing when you need it for GTK. After several 1000 lines you are not that happy when debugging.